# how to fix "error: terminating connection due to administrator command" vercel postgresql

Tags: postgresql, vercel, medusajs

I am trying to install medusajs by running this command
`npx create-medusa-app --db-url "postgres://default:password@ep-flat-bar-2078.us-east-1.aws.neon.tech:5432/verceldb?sslmode=require"`

and I keep getting error

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

error: terminating connection due to administrator command. 

Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at: at Client._handleErrorEvent 
(/Users/user/.npm/_npx/cc876d312f16923e/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:341:10)
```

What is this error and is it on Vercel side or Medusajs. How can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

That means that either somebody or something called `pg_terminate_backend()` to kill your session, or that the server was shut down with a fast shutdown request. Look at the PostgreSQL server log to determine the exact cause.

PostgreSQL doesn't do that on its own. Something in your stack is probably messing with the database.

Comment: How is this happening it is a one-line command, from the medusajs docs

Comment: I cannot tell you what shuts down your database / kills your user. Did you follow my advice to look into the PostgreSQL log?